# The page you requested was not found - Resubmit a form using csrf protection CI

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

when trying to manually reload the form...getting 404 error.

The page you requested was not found - 404

Comment: 404 is not the error that a failed CSRF test produces. The expected error is 403 and the message "The action you have requested is not allowed.'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this - extended the MY_Securtiy class and redirect the page on referer.

`create a file in application\core\MY_Security.php`

```
/*  by Piku -trying to handle csrf resubmission error msg
 */

class MY_Security extends CI_Security {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();      
    }

    public function csrf_show_error()
    {
        header('Location: ' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), TRUE, 200);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a spectacularly poor answer as the solution short-circuits CSRF protection.

Comment: @DFriend i tried the above answers and its working....but if its a poor answer please explain the correct way to do this....is it any other way to do this?

Comment: The problem with the answer is it is like hearing a fire alarm then telling everyone there is no fire and turning off the alarm without checking if there is a fire or not. It is impossible to explain how to solve the problem because there is no code demonstrating the problem.